# Bitbucket: How to create a list of issues from multiple repositories?

Tags: bitbucket

We have several repositories on BitBucket. For every repository we 
have the issue tracker enabled. For our progress reports I would like 
to be able to see all issues from all related repositories in one 
overview.

Is this possible and how can it be done?

Thanks, 
Paul

Answer (score 1):

Bitbucket [has an API](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BBDEV/Bitbucket+Developer+Documentation). You could quickly put together a script (or webpage using JSONP) calling:

https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/USERNAME/REPOSITORY/issues/

for each repository? (Replacing USERNAME and REPOSITORY with appropriate values)

For something more advanced you could query the USER, get all their repositories, then iterate.

Answer (score -1):

I needed the same thing today so I made the following python script [available here on github.](https://github.com/paulfurley/get-bitbucket-issues)

The two API call URLs you need are

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/user/repositories/
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/{owner}/{slug}/issues/
```

You'll have to authenticate with your BitBucket credentials which I did using the python requests library:

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(_USERNAME, _PASSWORD))
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Good point, I've now tried to include the essential bits of the code so that someone could re-create if github ever disappeared.